# when to use "su -l loginname -c somecommand"?

Tags: su

I tend to use `su - loginname  -c somecommand`.
Any different having argument `-l`? That is `su -l loginname -c somecommand`?

Answer (score 1):

The [man page for `su`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1@@shadow-utils.html) my Linux has, puts `-` and `-l` as equivalent, except for a minor difference in how `su` parses its command line.

> `-, -l, --login`
>     Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had
>      the user logged in directly.
>
> When - is used, it must be specified before any username. For
>              portability it is recommended to use it as last option, before
>              any username. The other forms (-l and --login) do not have this
>              restriction.